# Styled media receiver source (Chromecast)

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-cast, chromecast

Currently, I am working on a chromecast integration of my app.
Currently, you are given 3 options for your cast receiver application

- Styled Media Receiver
- Default media receiver
- Custom media receiver

I really like the styling of the styled media receiver, as it is very easy to style your receiver this way. However, sometimes I would be really like to extend the functionality of that receiver. Like a volume indicator, for example.

Is there a way I can obtain the source code of the styled media receiver? I checked the Github of google-cast but couldn't find it. Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, source for the first two options that you had listed are not publicly available

Comment: Are there any plans to make this publicly available? Because I think i am not the only one who wants to extend the functionality of the Styled media receiver. And currently budget does not allow me to make the receiver 100% custom

Comment: Sorry, but we can't discuss or speculate on future plans. In your particular case, the Cast device shows a volume indicator when user changes the volume and that is done outside of the receiver code, so you have that no matter what receiver you use. If there are other generic features that you think will be of public interest, you are welcome to open a feature request and if we find it useful for the majority of the user, we may add that to our receivers.